# Kendall correlation between $X$ and $X^2$

Tags: self-study, correlation, kendall-tau

Let $X \sim N(0, 1)$. Can you confirm that the Kendall's correlation coefficient between $X$ and $X^2$ is equal to $0$. The way I interpret this, is that Kendall's tau only measures monotonic dependence.

Comment: Also Pearson's correlation is zero. The reason is the symmetry of your density around 0: for positive x, you have a positive dependency between x and its square. For negative x,the relation is negative but of equal strength.

Comment: @Mayer: Thank you for the intuition. Then, we agree on the fact that tau = 0 because Kendall's tau only measures monotonic dependence... isnt'it ?

Comment: Not fully. Symmetry of the density around 0 will lead all reasonable measures of correlation (also such that consider non-monotone relationships) to say 'no dependency'. But how to prove this claim?

Comment: Kendall's tau makes no sense in this context: it can be defined only for finite sets of *observations,* not for a continuous distribution like a Normal. You could make this a meaningful question by asking about the expectation of Kendall's tau among random samples of a Normal variate, if that's the sort of thing you have in mind.

Comment: @whuber: Coming from U-statistics theory, Kendall's tau is estimating the probability of drawing a concordant pair of points from the bivariate distribution minus the probability of a discordant pair. Couldn't this theoretical version of Kendall's tau be computed for the distribution of $(X, X^2)$?

Comment: @Michael: That looks like a very nice way to interpret the question. Your argument immediately proves the value is $0$ for any distribution of $X$ that is symmetric about $0$.

Comment: @MichaelM could you consider posting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The population version of Kendall's $\tau$ (probability of concordance minus the probability of discordance) between $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\tau(Z_1,Z_2) &= P\left[ (Z_1 - Z_1^*) (Z_2 - Z_2^*) > 0 \right] - P\left[ (Z_1 - Z_1^*) (Z_2 - Z_2^*) < 0 \right]\\
&= 2\ P\left[ (Z_1 - Z_1^*) (Z_2 - Z_2^*) > 0 \right] - 1
\end{align*}
where $(Z_1,Z_2)$ and $(Z_1^*,Z_2^*)$ are iid distributed.

Now remark that $x < y$ and $x^2 < y^2$ if and only if $|x| < y$, which you can see by noting that
$$
x^2 < y^2\ \Leftrightarrow\ |x| < |y|,
$$
and evaluating the three possibilities
\begin{align*}
x < y < 0 &: \quad x^2 \not< y^2 \quad \text{and} \quad |x| \not< y\\
x < 0 < y &: \quad x^2 < y^2 \ \Leftrightarrow \ |x| < y\\
0 < x < y &: \quad x^2 < y^2 \quad \text{and} \quad |x| < y.\\
\end{align*}

We're all set to prove the result. Letting $Y \sim N(0,1)$ be an independent copy of $X$, we get
\begin{align*}
P\left[ (X - Y) (X^2 - Y^2) > 0 \right] &= P\left[ X > Y \quad \text{and} \quad X^2 > Y^2 \right] + P\left[ X < Y \quad \text{and} \quad X^2 < Y^2 \right]\\
&= P\left[\ |Y| < X \right] + P\left[\ |X| < Y \right]\\
&= 2\ P\left[\ |X| < Y \right].
\end{align*}
That you can compute in many ways, (here I skip some obvious steps)
\begin{align*}
P\left[\ |X| < Y \right] &= (.5)\ P\left[\ |X| < Y\ |\ Y > 0 \right]\\
&= (.5)\ P\left[\ X < Y\ |\ Y > 0, X>0 \right]\\
&= (.5)(.5) = .25\\
\end{align*}

You therefore get $\tau(X,X^2) = 2*2*(.25) - 1 = 0$. We never use the normality assumption... Only that the distribution is symmetric about 0.